# Develop Desktop App With Electron And Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I have a problem developing (creating the environment of) a desktop application using Electron and Angular. This app, at some point, has to fire a `showOpenDialog` which is specific to Electron in order to select a directory from the File System. Let's say I have the following angular component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <button (click)="openDirectory()">Open directory</button>
        <p> {{selectedDirectory}} </p>
    `
})

export class AppComponent {

    selectedDirectory: string = "None";
    openDirectory() {
        // Here I need to call the 'showOpenDialog' from electron
        // and update the selectedDirectory property
    }

}
```

... but calling `showOpenDialog` in `openDirectory` won't work and it will return a compilation error because Angular doesn't have a clue who `showOpenDialog` really is.
In a tipical Electron application you will write something like:

```
const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;

var path = dialog.showOpenDialog({
    properties: ['openDirectory']
});
```

Now I have to build the Angular project, modify the `bundle.js` file and finally add the electron functionalities like `showOpenDialog` and so on. After that I need to copy the distribution files into Electron project. I know, this is a really mess.
Q: What would be a better way to develop this kind of application? Like both Angular and Electron environments in the same project.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to install electron (and its types) within your angular app, then import your dependency

Installation:

```
npm install electron @types/electron
```

usage:

```
import { remote } from 'electron';


openDirectory() {
    remote.showOpenDialog();
}
```

Comment: Not working Sir. You get `Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function`. I have to use `require` somehow

Comment: Does this happen at runtime?

Comment: Yes, at runtime. I used `win.loadURL('http://localhost:4200');` in Electron

Comment: So, the compilation error is solved. Not knowing well electron, I can't assist any further. Maybe this can be helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43966353/electron-angular-fs-existssync-is-not-a-function