# Angular&Electron - Open link in default browser

Tags: angular, electron, fs

I'm trying to open a link from an electron app (using angular) on my default browser but I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:160955)
    at Object../node_modules/electron/index.js (vendor.bundle.js:160961)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at Object../src/app/components/issue/issue.component.ts (main.bundle.js:159)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at Object../src/app/app.module.ts (main.bundle.js:75)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at Object../src/main.ts (main.bundle.js:644)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at Object.0 (main.bundle.js:662)
```

I've got a "(click)="onNavigate()"" on a button on my html component
and this is the function:

```js
import { shell } from 'electron';
...      
onNavigate() {
    shell.openExternal("http://www.google.com");
}
...
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong and hope someone here can help me :)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43966353/electron-angular-fs-existssync-is-not-a-function

Comment: I tried but im still new to all this ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `window.require` instead of `require` is one way of avoiding the conflict between `require` since you're using `webpack` & it brings it's own `require`. Try:

```
const shell = window.require('electron');
...      
onNavigate() {
   shell.openExternal("http://www.google.com");
}
...
```

Comment: It kept opening the new window inside the scope of the app so I got over the problem using this way: 
mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', (event, url) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        electron.shell.openExternal(url);
    })

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing in my App, handling it in the main process. I probably should've added it as an alternative on the answer.